# Find the probability of flopping a straight, given you have 2 hole cards that can flop a straight

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

Find P(flop straight | dealt 2 hole cards that can flop a straight)

At first I simply did:
$\frac{12}{50} \times \frac{8}{49} \times \frac{4}{48} = 0.003$ but that seems awfully low.

Then I tried combinatorics with ${}^{11}C_3 \times {}^{4}C_1 \div {}^{50}C_3 = 0.037$

I then realize that some hole cards have a bigger range. E.g: 2-6 suited must flop 3-4-5 to get a straight, whereas J-10suited can flop Q-K-A, or 9-Q-K or 8-9-Q or 7-8-9

How do I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, and ace + deuce are two cards that are consecutive but also have only one way to flop a straight with.  The problem is very messy, I seriously doubt this is what your professor intended.  You were assigned this problem?  Are you sure this is the full statement of the problem?  Also, suits are irrelevant to getting straights.

Comment: Obviously you can compute this case-by-case, but I don't see a short/clever way of doing this. But that's probably my lack of imagination...

Comment: There is also the cases where straights formed are actually straight flushes and you would have to discount those.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear to me what game is being played, so I assumed that the game is five-card stud.  It will be easy to adapt the calculations to a different game, since the only difficulty is counting the number of two-card combinations that could result in a straight.

Let $T$ be the event that the first two cards could be part of a straight and let $S$ be the event that a straight is flopped.  We are asked to compute $$\Pr(S|T)=\frac{\Pr(S\cap T)}{\Pr(T)}=\frac{\Pr(S)}{\Pr(T)}$$

$\Pr(S)$ is easy to compute; there are $10$ possible straights, from $5$-high through Ace-high, and each can occur in $4^5-4=1020$ ways, so $$\Pr(S)=\frac{10200}{\binom{52}{5}}=\frac5{1274}$$ To compute $\Pr(T)$, we need to know the number of two-card patterns that could be part of a straight.  Say there are $t$ such patterns, ignoring suits.  Then $$\Pr(T)=\frac{16t}{\binom{52}{2}}=\frac{8t}{663}$$

The problem is to compute $t$ systematically, so that we can be sure we have counted each pattern exactly once.  I think we ought to organize the two-card hand according to the number of possibilities (that is, 3-card combinations, ignoring suits) to complete the straight.

- One-chance hands: A$2$ through A$5$, $10$A through KA, and $x,x+4$ where $x$ runs from $2$ through $9$, giving $16$ patterns.
- Two-chance hands: $23$ through $25$, $10$K through QK, and $x,x+3$ where $x$ runs from $3$ through $9$, giving $13$ patterns.
- Three-chance hands: $34$, JQ, and $x,x+2$ where $x$ runs from $3$ through $10$, giving $10$ patterns.
- Four-chance hands:  $x,x+1$, where $x$ runs from $4$, through $10$, giving $7$ patterns.

To check, we count how many straights are produced:
$$16\cdot1+13\cdot2+10\cdot3+7\cdot4=100$$
On the other hand, there are $10$ possible straights, and $\binom52=10$ ways of choosing two cards from one of them, so again we get $10\cdot10=100$, and the count appears to be correct.

Now, $t=16+13+10+7=46$ and $$\Pr(S|T)=\frac{5\cdot663}{1274\cdot8\cdot46}=\frac{255}{36064}\approx0.00707$$